# Translations for AngularJS module angularMoment

Tags: angularjs, angular-moment

I use angularMoment module in my app to display post creation time like few seconds ago, 2 hours ago and so on. The problem is that my app supports multiple languages. How do I make translations for it?

I used this tutorial to implement angularMoment https://scotch.io/tutorials/display-time-relatively-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in angularMoment documentation you can do:

> If you need internationalization support, load specified moment.js
>   locale file first:
>
> `<script src="components/moment/locale/de.js"></script>` 
>   Then call the
>   `amMoment.changeLocale()` 
>   method (e.g. inside your app's run() callback):

The changeLocale function changes the local for moment.js and updates all the am-time-ago directive instances. This function accepts two arguments locale and an object with overrides. The locale is a string of the Locale code eg. en, es, ru etc.